# /usr/lib/cnf-update-db: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'CommandNotFound' when doing "sudo apt update"

Tags: apt, kubuntu, python

whenever I try to run `sudo apt update` or `sudo apt-get update`, I keep getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/cnf-update-db", line 8, in <module>
    from CommandNotFound.db.creator import DbCreator
ImportError: No module named 'CommandNotFound'
Reading package lists... Done
E: Problem executing scripts APT::Update::Post-Invoke-Success 'if /usr/bin/test -w /var/lib/command-not-found/ -a -e /usr/lib/cnf-update-db; then /usr/lib/cnf-update-db > /dev/null; fi'
E: Sub-process returned an error code
[1]    120555 exit 100   sudo apt update
```

I'm on Kubuntu 20.04 and my Python version is `2.5.2`. I have compiled Python 3.6, 3.7 and 3.8 and tried, but still the same issue.

When I try to install `python3-apt` (as given in some similar questions), I get:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
python3-apt is already the newest version (2.0.0ubuntu0.20.04.5).
python3-apt set to manually installed.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] 
Setting up python3-setuptools (45.2.0-1) ...
E: py3compile:243: Requested versions are not installed
dpkg: error processing package python3-setuptools (--configure):
 installed python3-setuptools package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 3
Setting up python3-wheel (0.34.2-1) ...
E: py3compile:243: Requested versions are not installed
dpkg: error processing package python3-wheel (--configure):
 installed python3-wheel package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 3
Errors were encountered while processing:
 python3-setuptools
 python3-wheel
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
[1]    120974 exit 100   sudo apt install python3-apt
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!